# How to Configure Zyxel USG60 router to connect to the internet using wan1 only for port 5 and 6

Tags: networking, router

Just want to ask how can I configure my USG60 router, because I want the
port 5 and 6 to connect to the internet using wan1 only and port 3 and 5 to
connect using wan2.

I've been searching all day now, I don't know how to do it.
I already ask the support of zyxel but they have not answered me yet
Can you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I went through this exact thing myself. Unless you have 2 different internet connections, you will not be able to split them. If you have two different connections you may be able to by setting the port rules to make them connect separately, but I know for a fact you cannot split the internet connection between the different LAN connections. I finally set the second ones to off and went with a single LAN. I believe the concept is if you want an "In-House" LAN only without any internet connection, or you want to have 2 separate ISP's, you can set them up like that, however that's all I could get figured out. I wanted to split my wireless from my LAN connections and it simply would not allow it.